# IIS , configure a website that serves static content only

Tags: iis, web

I want to setup a website on IIS and only serve static content on that website(html,css,js,images,...).

Is it enough to change the .NET version to 'No managed code' in the IIS apppool to prevent any code from being executed?

I have other websites that do have asp.net code so I cannot just Uninstall the dynamic iis features.